# Cades Signature verfication fails for large data

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, java-11

I have implemented a Cades-BES detached signature solution using Java 11 and BouncyCastle.
A third-party server is validating the signature, and I do not have access to that server's verification process.

The issue is, the signed data is verifying fine for data size  up to 25kb,
but the verification is failing for 25kb and above.

I keep on getting, **"message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value[message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value]"** from the server,

but it is getting verified for data below 25kb.

Can you please help me understand if the issue could have been in my logic or is there any limitation in the signature of huge data?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems that either your code or the server code doesn't calculate the message digest correctly

Comment: but wont that happen for strings below 25kb?

Comment: Use another app to generate a CADES detached signature, for example, https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/sign-a-document, and test the result against your server

Comment: 25kb is the failing threshold size for the signature? or for the document being signed?

Comment: the document is getting signed. but it is failing in verification.

Comment: You can also use https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation to validate your generated signatures

Comment: ok I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: one more question, is CAdes-BES similar to Cades ?

Comment: CAdES-BES is a profile for CAdES that requires some signed properties to be added to the signature. So all CAdES-BES signatures are valid CAdES signatures, but not all CAdES signatures are valid CAdES-BES.

Comment: Hi, So after certain discussion it seems that the end-user requires CAdES-BES and not CAdES , so all I have to do, is to add the additional attributes. I have understood about the certificateAttribute and MessageDigestAttribute, can you please help me to understand what is required in the Content-Type attribute ? If this is a different requirement then I will ask a new Question.

Comment: the mime content type, like "text/plain" or "application/pdf"